# jquery wait for multiple complete events

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, events

I want to use jQuery's `load` function to load some content into a div, and I want to also call jQuery's `animate` function.

```
$('#div1').load('...', function() {
    // load complete
});

$('html,body').animate({
    ...: ...}, ..., '...', function(){
    // animate complete
});
```

I don't want to wait for `load` to complete before calling `animate` or vice versa.

Following this I want to call a third function, but I don't want to call it until the complete event for both the `load` and the `animate` have been fired.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Sounds like a job for `Deferred`: http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

```
var load = $.Deferred(function (dfd) {
  $('#div1').load(…, dfd.resolve);
}).promise();

var animate = $('html,body').animate(…);

$.when(load, animate).then(function () {
  // Do your thing here!
});
```

Comment: `.animate(…)` does not return a deffered! (and I think that `.load` doesn't either...)

Comment: Actually, animations work like deferreds: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/7934.

I'm not sure how `.load` works.

Comment: WOW! I didn't know that! What's interesting though, is that the *jQuery collection itself* becomes the deferred: http://jsfiddle.net/jgbUX/ . **Really interesting.**

Comment: @joseph-silber: I'm happy that you discovered something new. :) I've checked `.load` and its return value is not a deferred, so I've updated my solution to wrap it manually.

Comment: Thanks -- one simple example can be worth 1000 words in documentation.  Learned too many new concepts.  Brain hurting..

Answer (score 5):

```
var _loadComplete = false;
var _animateComplete = false;

$('#div1').load('...', function() {
    // load complete
    _loadComplete = true;
    checkComplete(); 
});

$('html,body').animate({
    ...: ...}, ..., '...', function(){
    // animate complete
    _animateComplete = true;
    checkComplete();
});

function checkComplete() {
    if(_loadComplete && _animateComplete)
        runThirdFunction();
});
```

Comment: definitely viable if you call `checkComplete()` from both the `.load()` and the `.animate()` dontcha think? ;)

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to keep count of how many of your events have completed, and then use that as a test in your callback:

```
var complete = 0;

$('#div1').load('...', function() {
    complete++;
    callback();
});
$('html,body').animate({
    ...: ...}, ..., '...', function(){
    complete++;
    callback();
});

function callback(){
    if ( complete < 2 ) return;
    // both are complete
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Set a flag in LoadComplete and call your own 'allComplete' function. 
Set another flag in AnimateComplete and call that same 'allComplete' function.

In allComplete you check if both flags are set. If they are, both async functions are complete and you can call your third function.

Instead of setting flags (separate variables), you can also add 1 to a global counter, that way, you can increase the number of async functions to wait for without having to introduce extra flag variables.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
$('#div1').queue(function(){ /* do stuff */ });
```

This way you can queue functions to execute one after the other.