# Wait for two events with jQuery and execute a callback when both are done

Tags: jquery

I have a `.click()` event on an element. After it's closed, this mob has a transition that happens and an AJAX call that goes through. That's all that happens.

What I need is a callback to put inside the `.click()` function to execute when both of those things are done, even if transitions aren't supported. Here's a timeline:

jQuery needs to wait for the ajax call and the transition, then execute the callback after the ajax call has completed AND the transition has either finished or not happened at all.

How can I do this? Thanks!

*NOTE: I'm using `$.ajax()` for the ajax call and a normal CSS3 transition on the element in question. I can detect transitionEnd with javascript event binding, I have a variable setup for that called transitionEnd and another variable that detects if the browser support transitions call supportsTrans.*

Comment: *(Ignore that duplicate, I chose the wrong question. I **have** seen at least a couple of variations on this question before, though.)*

Comment: No, because mine involves the transitionEnd event, making it a bit more complex.

Comment: @Jackson: Yes, I choose the wrong question and edited the comment. At the end of the day, though, this comes down to: How do I wait until two things have happened? I've definitely seen that question before, and the answer is trivial.

Comment: I know answer is already done and checked, but how about deferred: http://jsfiddle.net/zerkms/SPqhB/ ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Two jQuery Event Handlers - execute code when both are fired](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5909988/two-jquery-event-handlers-execute-code-when-both-are-fired)

Comment: I would use jQuery's Deferred object, which is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7432815/jquery-wait-for-multiple-complete-events

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a flag for each event, initially false. Hook the two events in question (`transitionEnd` and the ajax `success`, it sounds like). Each event sets its flag and calls a function. That function checks the flags: If both are set, it does something.

Here's an example using `animate` rather than a CSS transition, just to keep things simple: [Live example](http://jsbin.com/orulan/2) | [source](http://jsbin.com/orulan/2/edit)

```
jQuery(function($) {

  $("#theButton").click(function() {
    this.style.display = "none";
    $("#box, #content").show();
    doTheStuff();
  });

  function doTheStuff() {
    var ajaxDone = false,
        ajaxFailed = false,
        animationDone = false;

    display("Triggering ajax and animation");

    $.ajax({
      url: "http://jsbin.com/ibebiv",
      method: "GET",
      success: function(data) {
        $("#content").append(data);
        display("ajax done");
        ajaxDone = true;
        checkDone();
      },
      error: function() {
        ajaxFailed = true;
        checkDone();
      }
    });

    $("#box").animate({
      left: "+200px"
    }, function() {
      display("animation done");
      animationDone  = true;
      checkDone();
    });

    function checkDone() {
      if ((ajaxDone || ajaxFailed) && animationFlag) {
        display("<strong>All done</strong>");
      }
    }
  }

  function display(msg) {
    $("<p>").html(msg).appendTo("#content");
  }
});
```

Note the error handling, in case the ajax call fails.

Comment: by flag, he meant just a variable I guess. Eg: flag++; inside your call backs of each of your events, and then calling the function itself. if (flag == 2 ) is true, it means both events have taken place.

Comment: @JacksonGariety: *"How do I set flags?"* `var flag = false;` and then later `flag = true;`

Comment: How do I get it to checkDone() to constantly be checking until it goes? Right now it'll just check once when the ajax call finishes.

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out. It checks twice. Once at the end of transition and once at the end of ajax. So then the last one will always have the callback! Genius!

Comment: @JacksonGariety: :-) I've just updated the example so it's all contained in a function, which is more realistic, rather than all being in the `ready` handler (which I suppose is also a function, but...).

Comment: In `$.ajax()`, `success:Function` is not guaranteed to be invoked. You'll still need to handle Ajax failure case, namely `error:Function` parameter, or, you may put the common logic in `complete:Function`.